# Setting up Active Directory, Adding Machines with Different OSes & adding a server with an instance of SQL

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, sql

I have 2 servers to manage at work, a Dell Poweredge with has a software called "Abecas" which uses SQL Server, The Poweredge is running Win Server 2008, there is no AD in place as of yet.

I have another server running Windows Server 2012 R2, its primary purpose is only to work as a backup as i have 4 x 4TB drives in a RAID 10 config.

The Poweredge backs up to the Raid server via Acronis through network share everyday.

If i setup AD on windows server 2012 and add all 8 machines we have in the office and then add the Poweredge server to the domain will it ruin the current SQL setup i have in place? I read that setting up AD on a machine that has a running instance of SQL is a bad idea after the fact because people get locked out of there SQL server - I cannot afford to have any downtime beyond the weekend as the company i work for uses this software to ship products out and receive shipments and handle billing as well.

So my question is if i used the backup server also as an A.D. install and then added the windows 2008 server to that domain, would i have issues accessing my SQL db? also would the client computers that use "Abecas" software to connect to the server to handle orders, would they lose connectivity as a result of the switch to A.D?

Thank you, I'm more of a Mac guy than a Windowsx guy but i'm trying to learn and take careful steps to avoid any major issues, I appreciate everyones assistance here.

Thank You !

Comment: `1.` Do the client machines only use the server for SQL or do they use it as a file or print server also? `2.` Seeing as this is a workgroup, I'm assuming you're using SQL authentication and not Windows authentication to connect from the clients to the SQL Server. If that's the case then joining the SQL Server to an AD domain shouldn't break your clients.

Comment: The poweredge server hosts a few folders that we map as network shares or "network drives" .. thr current setup is that users can deposit files into these shares but cannot delete files. 

Thr other task this machine handles is that sql server that is utilized by abecas server, the abecas clients on the end user machines connect to the server and I believe the usernames for abecas are created in abecas, I believe the system uses local authentication... 

When I open sql management server I just click connect and I'm in, I don't enter in any administrator passwords or anything like that.. what

Comment: What should I look out for to verify what type of authentication my sql management server uses?

Comment: The good news is that usually SQL Login method is the norm for workgroup scendarios. To check your SQL authentication mode, in SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server name and choose Properties. Click Security on the left side, then you should see the authentication mode. If it is set to SQL and Windows authentication, you still need to check each database... Right click each database, choose Properties, then Permissions. You will have to look at the list of users and figure out if they are SQL accounts or Windows accounts.

Comment: @dre, I checked as you had instructed and i see it is listed as SQL & Windows Authentication, When i open up Sql Management and it asks to login, it looks like it logs in using windows authentication. 

So what would be the following steps or ways i could be sure that adding this server to a current active directory server will not break the SQL login system for client machines?

Comment: Well, on one hand, adding this server as a member of the domain should not affect the local accounts that already exist on the server. That said, I recommend contacting the application vendor and letting them know your situation.